# How do I remove Netlify CLI from my package.json file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json

I installed Netlify CLI on my react app and it came with thousands of lines on my package.json file. Is there an alternative way to delete apart from selecting and deleting?

Comment: if you are using NPM, just uninstall it: npm uninstall netlify-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing what Fabio said:

use the npm uninstall command

```
npm uninstall netlify-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have installed netlify-cli with -g flag

```
 npm uninstall netlify-cli -g
```